# Naming convention for Rx extension methods?

Tags: naming-conventions, system.reactive

So if I'm writing an extension method for a type in another library that converts that type into an Rx `IObservable<T>`, what exactly is the convention? I ask because I thought `AsObservable` was the way to go, but I've also seen `ToObservable`. It's unclear to me which is used when or if there's any real convention at all.

Could it be `ToObservable` is reserved for turning something that is expected to product a single event into an `IObservable<T>` where as `AsObservable` is reserved for converting something that is expected to produce a sequence of events into an `IObervable<T>`?

Comment: See also [Bart De Smet on *Observations on IQbservable - The Dual of IQueryable* at ~12:55](https://channel9.msdn.com/Shows/Going+Deep/Bart-De-Smet-Observations-on-IQbservable-The-Dual-of-IQueryable), where he talks about the `To`-prefix.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Unless you have a very good reason to write your own cross-duality operators, you will not need to write a "To" postfix when dealing with Enumerables and Observables.

Observe the following truths:

- [`ToObservable`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh212140%28v=vs.103%29.aspx) is expected to convert *pull-based* sequences into *push-based* sequences.
- [`ToEnumerable`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh212132%28v=vs.103%29.aspx) is expected to convert *push-based* sequences into *pull-based* sequences.
- [`AsObservable`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh211761%28v=vs.103%29.aspx) is expected to wrap a *push-based* type as `IObservable< T >`.
- [`AsEnumerable`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb335435.aspx) is expected to wrap a *pull-based* type as `IEnumerable< T >`.

Therefore, `To` should be used when you're writing a method which switches the duality of the source, and `As` should be used when the resulting duality is the same as the source's.

In most cases, you will be using `As` for your own methods, because the cross-duality operators of `ToObservable` and `ToEnumerable` have already been written for you.

Sources: Personal experience, MSDN documentation (above), Erik Meijer himself.

Comment: I would further generalise the above by pointing out AsObservable was formerly named Hide. It is useful for hiding the underlying type especially if the underlying type is an ISubject. Even if you return a subject via a Method that is IObservable`1 it could be cast back to subject and tampered with. Hide/AsObservable prevents this tampering. Considering this, I would name anything that projects from a non IObservable to an IObservable 'ToObservable', this includes IEnumerable sources.

Comment: Precisely! I've updated the answer to use the phrasing "wraps... as" instead of "casts... to" to make this more apparent.

Answer (score 5):

I don't know of any official guidance, but the main metric I would use is to look at the amount of work you are doing.  For most cases, there is a non-trivial amount of work being done (which is subjective in itself), such as turning an IEnumerable into an IObservable, and I would use `ToObservable`.  When the method does fairly trivial work, as with the `Observable.AsObservable` extension method, `AsObservable` seems the better choice.  Another notable difference between these two methods is that `AsObservable` is not much more than a type cast and doesn't make any real changes to behavior of the argument, but `Observable.ToObservable(IEnumerable<T>)` returns an object with significantly different semantics.

Comment: Good advice. I'd go further and say that AsXxx should only be a cast (to force the compiler to choose the desired extension method: cf. LINQ AsQueryable/AsEnumerable, or the C# "as" keyword), while anything involving a conversion should prefer ToXxx or FromXxx (e.g. FromAsyncPattern). This fits Observable.AsObservable, whose only real use is to force the compiler to choose an IObservable (client-side) extension method over the IQbservable (server-side) equivalent.

Comment: Good points, however not entirely true about the '..only real use (of AsObservable...'. I would argue that it's primary role it to protect you from consumers tampering with your underlying type i.e. being able to cast your type back to a subject and then call OnNext/OnError/OnComplete on it.